# Opacity применяется к нежелательному блоку

Tags: html, css

Как мне сделать чтобы `opacity` применялось только к классу `cart`, но не к классу `hid`

```css
.cart {
  border: 1px solid #EFECEC;
  margin: 10px;
}

.cart:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.hid {
  display: none;
}

.cart:hover .hid {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10em;
  margin-left: 7em;
  font-size: large;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class=" col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12  cart ">
  <div class='hid'><a href="productPage.php#${key}">Перейти</a></div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="pro-img">
      <img src="pages/orderPage/goods/${data[key].img}" width="100em" height="100em">
    </div>
    <div class="prod">
      <h4 class='name'>${data[key].name}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: При такой верстке ни как...  `opacity` - наследуется...

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста,как умнее тогда сделать

Comment: сделать эти блоки соседями

Answer (score 0):

Если задача в том, чтобы сделать прозрачными все элементы внутри `.cart` кроме `.hid`, можно воспользоваться таким правилом:

```
.cart:hover *:not(.hid){
  opacity: 0.8
}
```

```css
.cart {
  border: 1px solid #EFECEC;
  margin: 10px;
}

.cart:hover *:not(.hid){
  opacity: 0.8
}

.hid {
  display: none;
}

.cart:hover .hid {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10em;
  margin-left: 7em;
  font-size: large;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class=" col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12  cart ">
  <div class='hid'><a href="productPage.php#${key}">Перейти</a></div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="pro-img">
      <img src="pages/orderPage/goods/${data[key].img}" width="100em" height="100em">
    </div>
    <div class="prod">
      <h4 class='name'>${data[key].name}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не помогает почему то

Comment: @КириллЧетвертков Добавил код на основе вашего примера. Нажмите синюю кнопку "Выполнить код"

Comment: а что можно сделать чтобы блок hid отображался в центре,то есть в блоке с классом cart, а не в его пределах как сейчас?

Comment: Убрать у него `position:absolute` и перенести после блока `.prod`